# How to toggle between two plotly charts with plain html, css, js

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

I am very new to javascript and need some initial acceleration from the forum to understand the javascript area better.

I am using plotly (python) to generate graphs from backend. I have two platforms and corresponding to them, two graphs would be generated from backend and substituted in HTML using Jinja2 syntax. I want to toggle between these two graphs with only one DIV element. Could you please guide me in doing so?
I tried with about 10-15 solutions provided using jQuery and jsfiddle but no luck.

```js
// Function to plot bar graph
function plot1(){
    var bar_graph = {{ bar_graph_json | safe }};
    Plotly.plot('chart1',bar_graph,{});
}

// Function to plot pie chart
function plot2(){
    var pie_chart = {{ pie_chart_json | safe }};
    Plotly.plot('chart1',pie_chart,{});
}

// When page loads, by default display the bar graph.
plot1();
```

```html
<!-- Page 4 -->
<section id="page-4" class="page">
    <!-- Button to be used for toggling between two graphs -->
    <button class="btn btn-link" onclick="plot2();"></button>

     <!-- Now I Need help here to configure the button to toggle between two graphs.
     Button name should change as per toggle // DIV tag for displaying the required chart and toggle between the two charts -->

    <div class="row chart" id="chart1">
    
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are able to generate the chart but need functionality to switch between them by pressing a button.

```js
// your logic to draw both charts
//Plotly.plot('chart1', bar_graph, {});
//Plotly.plot('chart2', bar_graph, {});

const toggleBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle-chart");
const charts = document.querySelectorAll(".chart");

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  charts.forEach(chart => {
    chart.classList.toggle("hide");
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<section id="page-4" class="page">
  <button class="btn btn-link btn-toggle-chart">Toggle Chart</button>

  <div class="row chart" id="chart1">
    <p>Demo Chart 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- hide second chart by default -->
  <div class="row chart hide" id="chart2">
    <p>Demo Chart 2</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<div class="row chart" id="chart1"></div>
<script>
            function plot1(){
                var bar_graph = {{ bar_graph_json | safe }};
                Plotly.plot(document.getElementById('chart1'),bar_graph,{});
            }

            function plot2(){
                var pie_chart = {{ pie_chart_json | safe }};
                Plotly.plot(document.getElementById('chart1'),pie_chart,{});
            }

          plot1();
          </script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define 2 buttons and hide the appropriate one when clicked.

```js
// Function to plot bar graph
function plot1() {
/*
  var bar_graph = {
    {
      bar_graph_json | safe
    }
  };
  Plotly.plot('chart1', bar_graph, {});
*/
  changeButtons();
}

// Function to plot pie chart
function plot2() {
/*
  var pie_chart = {
    {
      pie_chart_json | safe
    }
  };
  Plotly.plot('chart1', pie_chart, {});
 */
  changeButtons();
}

// Change the buttons
function changeButtons() {
  const buttons = [...document.getElementsByClassName("btn")];
  buttons.map( (button) => button.classList.toggle("hide") );
}

// When page loads, by default display the bar graph.
plot1();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="page-4" class="page">
  <button class="btn btn-link" onclick="plot1();">Bar graph</button>
  <button class="btn btn-link hide" onclick="plot2();">Pie chart</button>
  <div class="row chart" id="chart1">
  </div>
</section>
```